# What is your read about this hand?

Tags: reading-hands

It's $1/$3 no limit holdem. I had $450 stack. I had A⋄J⋄ in early position.

**PreFlop**:

- I raised to $15.
- A mid position player with large stack size (about $700) re-raised to $45
- Everyone folded to me.
- I called.

**Flop**:

- Flop came A♥ 3⋄ 7♠
- I checked
- Villain bet $200

What should I do? What do you think he is playing with?

Answer (score 2):

I think it was a mistake for you to check the flop. His pre-flop raise might well be something like AK/AQ, but it might also be QQ, KK, etc. If you check an A-high flop, he has to bet his QQ, and you have to fold. If you had bet first, his raise or call would have given you more information.

Answer (score 1):

It depends.

How much often is your openning making preflop 3-BETs? How much is your oponnent making flop C-BETs?

At online games, a look at the HUD can help you.

Apparently, he can have AQ or AK. With no info a fold is perfectly fine.